# Dapper return single value

Tags: c#, t-sql, dapper

I want to perform this simple test to see whether a table exists. I thought it would be easy just to return an int value depending on whether the table exists.

Below is what I have tried and doesn't work:

```
result = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(@"
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '@tableSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = '@tableName'))
    RETURN 0;


RETURN 1;
", new { tableSchema, tableName });
```

Error Message:

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

It's something really noddy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

It does not return the return value of your SQL statements. You could simply use

```
SELECT 1
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableSchema
AND    TABLE_NAME   = @tableName
```

Then you can use `ExecuteScalar` and it will return `1` if the table exists. Please note that I also corrected your parameters in the SQL statements. They must not be delimited by `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IF..ELSE statement you can use the following query and check whether the result is greater than zero.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '@tableSchema' AND      
TABLE_NAME = '@tableName'
```

BTW your query has syntax error, that's why you are seeing that error.

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are correct and make sense. But you should create a stored procedure that does this check. That way you will have less chance to have syntax errors and way easier to fix.

I recommend that the procedure accepts schema name and table name as parameters. Then select 0 or select 1 depending if found table or not. Dapper can execute procedures, no prob.

Comment: The only issue, this program is merely a test console, that is to make sure that the computer it is running on can see the database and a specified table. So the database could be any, and might not have the stored procedure...

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated, you are getting error becase your SQL query contains error. Try running it directly in SQL and you will se the same error. 
If your values suppose to show number of tables you are returning, then Karthik AMR solution seems the best one.

If values 1 and 0 is not really a count of how many tables exists, but also could be some chars, then this could also work:

```
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Users') THEN 'Y'   
      ELSE 'N'   
   END
```

Comment: I did run it in sql, just with out the returns... but I see where the two things are the same